# Draggable skinablePopupContainer

Tags: apache-flex, flex4

I have create a skinablePopupContainer with titlewindow inside as shown in tutorial below
but I am stuck at how to make it draggable , so that it can moved around the screen by clicking on titlebar of titlewindow which is inside the popupcontainer

http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/articles/flex-mobile-development-tips-tricks-pt4.html

Can you please suggest a way out?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [ObjectHandles](http://www.rogue-development.com/objectHandles.html) by Rogue-Development.com and the [Pantaste Library](http://blog.comtaste.com/2009/06/example_of_implementation_of_t_1.html).

Comment: What do you mean you need spark (layouts I presume) to drag the title window? Do you want to move the spark TitleWindow inside the Container, or do you want to move the Container across the screen?

Comment: Yes, so what is wrong with ObjectHandles or the Pantaste Library then? They do exactly what you need. You can also use [MoveManager](http://code.google.com/p/flexspaces/source/browse/trunk/FlexSpaces/src/flex/utils/spark/resize/MoveManager.as?r=157) by Chris Callendar, which should just do the trick.